# is url active storage with rails_blob_path valid to use in meta tags

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, meta-tags, rails-activestorage

I have Model User that has one `avatar`, and I set **meta tag** for `og:image` with `rails_blob_path`, I set this in the controller and the result of URL of it likes:

`myappname/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZpud9--aa382324e6d9968973/thepic-here-3783384.jpg?disposition=attachment`

this is if in `development` mode, if it is in `production` would it be valid for that URL to set into **meta tags** `og:image` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a full URL, in that case. Particularly, I use the handy [url_for](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/RoutingUrlFor/url_for) method, as follows:

```
url_for(asset.variant(
                resize_to_limit: [max_width, max_height]
              ))
```

Also, I've found that for certain apps to correctly parse your image (Whatsapp for instance), it's better to exclude the scheme (*https* or *http*), thus getting a metatag like:

```
<meta property="og:image" itemprop="image" content="//yourcoolsite.com/rails/active_storage/representations/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBBbDhFIiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--0507940c0531918f2c8a85ec0eba799b5a291789/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdCam9VY21WemFYcGxYM1J2WDJ4cGJXbDBXd2/logo.jpg">
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: did u use thi in production? i tried this and the twitter:image not showing off